# What is Task.Current?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, msdn

This question ([Is there a way to tell which Tasks are currently running in Task Parallel Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1551537/1580088)) says that you can access the currently running Task by the Task.Current property. But I can't find any such property in the documentation.

Why is this?

Comment: Based on the fact that even the other question states that it does not work and there are answers that do work, this question seems to be pretty pointless. Even if you find it... it won't help you.

Comment: As in the Thread said, there is no such Property.
You might think about

    TaskScheduler.Current

The question is, what Informations do you need from the Task?

Comment: The answer only states that there is no way to access all running tasks (not just one) and neither the answer nor the comments contradict the OP's claim that the Task.Current property exists so I thought maybe I missed something.

Comment: And the utility of it might be that I could schedule a continuation task to run right after I finish.

Answer (score 1):

What would you want `Task.Current` to be, **had it been there**? Consider this:

```
async Task DoAsync()
{
    var currentTask = Task.Current; // imagine Task.Current does exist

    await Task.Delay(1000);
}

// ...

var task = Task.Run(() => DoAsync());
```

Would you want `currentTask` to be the task returned by `Task.Run` or by `DoAsync`?

Perhaps, a less contrived question would be this:

**How to access the `Task` object from the task's own action?**

You certainly **cannot** do it the following way, as it has a race condition:

```
Task task = null;
task = Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine({ task.Id }));
```

You **can** however do it this way:

```
Task task = null;
task = new Task(() => Console.WriteLine({ task.Id }));
task.Run();
```

Is it what you're looking for? In my experience, I only once needed something like this:

**[Task sequencing and re-entracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21424084/task-sequencing-and-re-entracy)**